# Remove array initialization code using Python and regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have a .h file that is automatically generated. In this .h file there are arrays that are initialized in the following manner.

```
char variable_1[1] = { 0 };
char variable_2[16] = 
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
char variable_3[128] = 
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};


char variable_4[63] = 
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
char variable_5[1] = { 0 };
char variable_6[32] = 
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

I am using the following regex in Python:

```
^char\s+variable_\w+\[\w*\]\s*=\s*\{\s*[0,]*\s*\};
```

This regex will only find variable_1, variable_2, variable_5 and variable_6. However I need find all instances of these arrays and remove the initialization and leave the array names.

```
char variable_1[1];
char variable_2[16];
char variable_3[128];
char variable_4[63];
char variable_5[1];
char variable_6[32];
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in Python?

Comment: Can't you simply leave off the part of the regex that matches the `= {...}` part, i.e., only use `^char\s+variable_\w+\[\w*\]`?

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking for whitespace inside the arrays. Try:

`^char\s+variable_\w+\[\w*\]\s*=\s*\{\s*[0,\s]*\s*\};`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the regex. I will try that and see if I will be able to work with that in Python.

Comment: I am not sure how to get this to work in Python because I have to open the file and the initialization code is on multiple lines.

Comment: You can either check for all matches in the entire file at once (use `read()` instead of `readlines()`) or you can modify the regex to ignore everything after the `=`.